# Replacing sub pathnames in lua doesn't work as expected

Tags: lua

I have the following code:

```lua
local a = "/Users/diego/Desktop/nvim-file-location/lua/nvim-file-location/init.lua"
local b = "/Users/diego/Desktop/nvim-file-location"

local r = a:gsub(b, "")

print("path:", a)
print("cwd:", b)
print("replaced:", r)
```

I expect the following output for the replaced one:

```
replaced: /lua/nvim-file-location/init.lua
```

But I get:

```
path: /Users/diego/Desktop/nvim-file-location/lua/nvim-file-location/init.lua
cwd: /Users/diego/Desktop/nvim-file-location
replaced: /Users/diego/Desktop/nvim-file-location/lua/nvim-file-location/init.lua
```

Why it's not working?

I've tried also this:

```lua
local a = "/user/diego/foo"
local b = "/diego/foo"

local r = a:gsub(b, "/diego")

print(r)
```

And the output is as expected!!

```
/user/diego
```

Why is this happening?
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to `string.gsub` (in this case `b`) is always interpreted as a [Pattern](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1). And in a pattern, the character `-` has a special meaning: It is the non-greedy version of `*`.

So the portion `m-f` of the pattern can match `f`, `mf` `mmf`, etc., but there is nothing to match a `-` verbatim, so it cannot match a string `m-f`.

To be able to use your pattern verbatim, you need to escape all special characters, as described in the Reference Manual linked above:

```lua
local b = "/Users/diego/Desktop/nvim%-file%-location"
```

Comment: Good explanation, I supposed could be something related to the `-` character. Now, the thing is that I'm getting that string from a function that returns the pathname. How can I escape all the `-` characters then?

Comment: I got it! `b:gsub("%-", "%%-")` thank you!